# How to compare the differences between two form files?

Tags: forms, git, compare

I try to find a way that can compare the difference of old and new form file, that's, what I add or delete or edit in form files. I could use Git to compare the binary files, how can I compare form files ? Any suggest is very appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: you use **not git**, but configured for git **differ**, which is external program. You have to find such program

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the structure of your files.

Try `vimdiff file1 file2`